# Newbie debug javascript - Pull cookie value and use as variable - not currently working

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

I am new to this but I have tried to put some code together, however I'm getting errors flagging up and it doesn't seem to work. I would like some input to help debug it.

I have a cookie called "country" saved with a value of "AZ". I want to pull this cookie using javascript and store it as a variable, then use it in my google map page. This is the code I have:

```
// Setup variable with blank value
var country_code ='';
// Use read_cookie function to pull "country" value from cookie
if (country_code) var country_code = read_cookie('country');
// Make sure its value is lower case (required)
country_code = country_code.toLowerCase();
```

And then a bit further down:

```
var input = document.getElementById('loc');
var options = { types: [], ComponentRestrictions({ 'country': country_code });};
var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
```

The first error is that I have too many brackets on the "componentrestriction" line. How should this be done? It looks like I am closing them correctly, I encase the componentrestrictions with ({}); and var options with {};

EDIT: This is the read cookie function code I found on stackoverflow:

```
// Reading Cookie V0.1
function read_cookie(key){
    var result;
    return (result = new RegExp('(?:^|; )' + encodeURIComponent(key) + '=([^;]*)').exec(document.cookie)) ? (result[1]) : null;
}
```

Comment: What's the value of `document.cookie`?

Comment: "country" cookie with a value of "US" in my case.

Comment: Check the single steps in the debugger or use `console.log(...)`. Any unneeded spaces, wrong case, ... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a semicolon inside the statement and to much brackets after ComponentRestrictions.

Write it this way:

```
var options = { 
       types: [], 
       ComponentRestrictions: { 
                          'country': country_code 
                              }
              };
```

Comment: And this should be a valid object now? I don't think so :)

Comment: You're close, very close :) It has to be `componentRestrictions` with a lowercase `c` at the beginning - [API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#adding_autocomplete)

Comment: @Andreas i was just on the syntactic side of the question, not the semantic :)

Answer (score 1):

For the component restrictions:

```
var input = document.getElementById('loc');
var options = { types: [], componentRestrictions: { 'country': country_code } };
var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
```

Comment: Thank you. I have corrected this but the code still doesnt seem to pull my cookie. Have I done anything else wrong? My console doesnt say anything wrong?

Comment: I haven't done much recently with cookies but I can refer you to this (http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp) which may provide a better way to interpret the cookies.

Comment: Don't recommend w3schools.com to anyone unless you hate him^^ Have a look at the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/) and [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.cookie) for cookies.

Comment: @Andreas - cute ... It was a starting point more than anything else. Thanks for the additional references.